# Tinytest add a file object not defined

Tags: meteor, tinytest

I'm having a problem with TinyTest. I have a test below

```js
Tinytest.add('x - template', function (test) {

    var t = new Widget("ddd");
    test.equal(t.html,"");

});
```

and this function in another file (test.js)

```
function Widget(html){
     this.html = html || "";
}
```

In my package.js :

```
Package.onTest(function(api) {
   api.use('tinytest');
   api.use('core:widgets');
   api.addFiles('client/test.js');
   api.addFiles('widgets-tests.js');
});
```

I can run my tests but I get this message :

```
x
 FAIL
    S: template
   - exception - message Widget is not defined
ReferenceError: Widget is not defined
at Package (packages/local-test:core:widgets/widgets-tests.js:12:1)
at [object Object].func (packages/tinytest/tinytest.js:636:1)
at packages/tinytest/tinytest.js:406:1
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
at packages/meteor/timers.js:6:1
at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:108:1)
```

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

Where are your two files and what are their names? Meteor takes a folder depth + alphabetic order approach to loading javascript files.

Therefore if your Tinytest file is in the same (or any sub) folder as your `test.js` file, and its filename starts with, say, "h", it will load *before* `test.js` and won't know about your `Test` function.

To make sure your `test.js` file loads first, you should put it either in a folder in the same folder as your Tinytest file. Or, in a `lib` folder in any parent folder.

[Learn more about file loading order in Meteor](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fileloadorder).